# Throwing 1004 Error Only On PC

Tags: vba, excel

VBA macro throwing Run-time error '1004':
PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

This error is only being thrown when the macro runs on PC. On a Mac, the macro runs seamlessly. Is there any reason the below macro would throw an error?

```
Option Explicit
Sub DCR()
Dim J As Integer
Dim K As Integer
Dim L As Range
Dim sDay As String
Dim sMonth As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iTarget As Integer
Dim dBasis As Date
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set L = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G7")
L.Copy
For Each Wb2 In Application.Workbooks
Wb2.Activate
Next



iTarget = 13
While (iTarget < 1) Or (iTarget > 12)
            iTarget = Val(InputBox("Numeric month?"))
    If iTarget = 0 Then Exit Sub
Wend
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Add


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
sTemp = Str(iTarget) & "/1/" & Year(Now())
dBasis = CDate(sTemp)

For J = 1 To 31
    sDay = Format((dBasis + J - 1), "dddd mm-dd-yyyy")
    sMonth = Format((dBasis), "yyyy-mm")
    If Month(dBasis + J - 1) = iTarget Then
        If J > Sheets.Count Then
            Sheets.Add.Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = sDay
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            Range("A1").Value = sDay
        Else
            If Left(Sheets(J).Name, 5) = "Sheet" Then
            Sheets(J).Name = sDay
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            Range("A1").Value = sDay
            Else
            Sheets.Add.Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = sDay
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            Range("A1").Value = sDay
            End If

        End If
    End If
Next J

For J = 1 To (Sheets.Count - 1)
    For K = J + 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Right(Sheets(J).Name, 10) > _
          Right(Sheets(K).Name, 10) Then
            Sheets(K).Move Before:=Sheets(J)
        End If
    Next K
Next J

Sheets(1).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Wb2.SaveAs Filename:="DCR_" + sMonth + ".xlsx"
'
End Sub
```

Comment: What line gives the error?

Comment: The Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues line of the Else statement: 

Else
   If Left(Sheets(J).Name, 5) = "Sheet" Then
            Sheets(J).Name = sDay
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that you are prematurely copying the source range to the clipboard, and somehow by the time when you try to paste the source range to the corresponding worksheet the clipboard is empty thus giving the error `1004`. As to why the Mac does not give an error I have no idea, probably none of the actions performed between the `L.Copy` and the `.PasteSpecial`  clears the clipboard or whatever the Mac uses. Nevertheless, it’s a bad practice to keep the items to be copied that long in the clipboard.

I have also done a review of your code and highlighted some points for improvement *(see comments below)*

```
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook                       'Here you set the Wb variable but is not used at all in the entire procedure
Set L = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G7")     'Here was an opportunity to use the `Wb` variable instead this line points to whatever workbook is active

'This is the cause of the error: here you copy `A1:G7` to the clipboard (1\2)
L.Copy

'This Loop Through All Open Workbooks Seems To Have No Purpose!
For Each Wb2 In Application.Workbooks
    Wb2.Activate
Next

'This is not efficient, if the user does not enter neither a valid number nor a zero it will go endlessly
'Also suggest to use Do...Loop for the reasons mentioned in the Tip of the page While...Wend Statement (see suggested pages)
iTarget = 13
While (iTarget < 1) Or (iTarget > 12)
            iTarget = Val(InputBox("Numeric month?"))
    If iTarget = 0 Then Exit Sub
Wend

'This way of setting the date is not efficient as it depends on knowing the date format used by the user machine
'Sugest to use instead the DateSerial Function (see suggested pages)
sTemp = Str(iTarget) & "/1/" & Year(Now())
dBasis = CDate(sTemp)

        If J > Sheets.Count Then
            Sheets.Add.Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

            'These lines are repeated for each "situation" of the sheets (three times)
            ActiveSheet.Name = sDay

            'This is the cause of the error(2\2): here you try to paste from an empty clipboard
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            Range("A1").Value = sDay
        Else
            If Left(Sheets(J).Name, 5) = "Sheet" Then
            Sheets(J).Name = sDay
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            Range("A1").Value = sDay
            Else
            Sheets.Add.Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = sDay
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Wb2.Sheets(J).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            Range("A1").Value = sDay
            End If

        End If
    End If
Next J

'This sort is redundant, instead have a more efficient process to add the required worksheets
For J = 1 To (Sheets.Count - 1)
    For K = J + 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Right(Sheets(J).Name, 10) > _
          Right(Sheets(K).Name, 10) Then
            Sheets(K).Move Before:=Sheets(J)
        End If
    Next K
Next J

Sheets(1).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Missed to restate the `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`
'This is very dangerous as the system will not advise when closing a workbook without saving it first.
'And it will result in losing all work done on that workbook!

'This will give an error if by any chance a workbook with same name is open
Wb2.SaveAs Filename:="DCR_" + sMonth + ".xlsx"
```

This is the revised code. 
For a deeper understanding of the resources used suggest to visit these pages:

[Application Members (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff198091.aspx), 
[On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx), 
[DateSerial Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264202.aspx)

[While...Wend Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264682.aspx), 
[Do...Loop Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278815.aspx), 
[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx)

```
Option Explicit

Sub DCR()
Dim rSrc As Range           'Source Range to be copied
Dim WbkTrg As Workbook      'Target Workbook to act upon
Dim sWbkTrg As String       'Target Workbook name
Dim WshTrg As Worksheet     'Target Worksheet to act upon
Dim sWshTrg As String       'Target Worksheet name
Dim bMonth As Byte
Dim dDate As Date
Dim bDay As Byte
Dim b As Byte

    Rem Application Settings OFF
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Rem Get User Input
    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        bMonth = InputBox("Enter month number (1 to 12) or 0 to cancel.")
        On Error GoTo 0
        b = 1 + b
        If bMonth = 0 Then GoTo ExitTkn
        If b = 3 Then GoTo ExitTkn
    Loop Until bMonth >= 1 And bMonth <= 12        

    Rem Set Target Range To Be Copied Into New Workbook
    Set rSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G7")

    Rem Add Target Workbook
    Set WbkTrg = Workbooks.Add
    sWbkTrg = "DCR_" & Format(DateSerial(Year(Now), bMonth, 1), "yyyy-mm") & ".xlsx"

    Rem Delete All Worksheets Minus One In Target Workbook
    Do
        With WbkTrg
            If .Sheets.Count = 1 Then Exit Do
            .Sheets(1).Delete
        End With
    Loop

    Rem Add Worksheet for each day of the month
    For bDay = 1 To 31
        Rem Set Date & Month
        dDate = DateSerial(Year(Now), bMonth, bDay)
        sWshTrg = Format(dDate, "dddd mm-dd-yyyy")

        If Month(dDate) = bMonth Then

            Rem Process Worksheets - Days
            With WbkTrg
                If bDay = 1 Then
                    Rem Process 1st Day
                    Set WshTrg = .Sheets(bDay)
                Else
                    Rem Add Remaining Days
                    Set WshTrg = .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
            End If: End With

            Rem Update Day Standard Data
            WshTrg.Name = sWshTrg
            With WshTrg.Range("A1")
                rSrc.Copy
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                .Value = sWshTrg
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

    End If: Next

    Rem Save Target Workbook
    Application.Goto WbkTrg.Sheets(1).Cells(1), 1
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks(sWbkTrg).Close    'Close Workbook If Open
    On Error GoTo 0
    WbkTrg.SaveAs Filename:=sWbkTrg

ExitTkn:
    Rem Application Settings ON
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```